# User profile answers and questions UI was better before

Tags: discussion, profile-page

(Not so) recent changes in the user profile UI, the answers and questions separators took a turn for the worse in my opinion, the previous presentation was more intuitive. This is not a major issue, nor am I one to go against progress, but I would like it to be more like it was before.

What say you?

Comment: [You're not alone but it's unclear how much ranting will actually change things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049/175248)

Comment: "Interesting" how they decided "Accepted Answer" being completely spelled out was more important than differentiating between 3000 votes and 3900 votes, given it's the only thing on that line with plenty of space in all resolutions to be complete

Comment: @Makoto one can only guess, my quota is filled for this one. Thanks for link btw, I suck at finding these, it makes sense that it's on meta SE given that the changes are global.

Comment: @KevinB Curious changes indeed, I also find intersting the fact that they rolled back the changes in the Summary separator.